# How to import a Postgres database into a docker container?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to import PostgreSql dump to docker container, but it doesn't work

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres
COPY postgres.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

version: "3.9"

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  db:
    build: ./DB
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=gamenews
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=321678
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=gamenews
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=321678
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**structure:**

[image]

docker compose up **LOGS**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsftS.png)

Comment: What leads you to conclude it doesn't work?  Does the database data volume already exist when you add the `COPY` line to the Dockerfile?  Is there any interesting output from `docker-compose logs db`?

Comment: @DavidMaze
ADD logs for more details.

Comment: Why are you not just using a proper Postgres image and then using `pg_restore` to load the dump?

Comment: You seem to have added a link to an image file instead of the actual logs.  They should be in plain-text form and included directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a proper Postgres image:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - '.:/app:rw'
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

Here's a list of all the tags you can use: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Just spin that up, your volume maps the data to your hd, so it's not ephemeral in the container, then you can run `pg_restore` on your dump file.